# Java module and Cycle exists in module dependencies, Module

Tags: java, package, modularity

I have 2 projects and

```
+ proj1 has
    + com.myproj1 has
        + Runner.class
        + Logger.class

+ proj2 has
    + com.myproj2 has
        + Test.class
        + Fact.class

module com.myproj1 {
    requires module com.myproj2;
    exports com.myproj1
}

module com.myproj2 {
    exports com.myproj2;
    requires module com.myproj1;// the problem is "Cycle exists in module 
    dependencies, Module... "
}
```

I use Test.class from com.myproj2 in com.myproj1 Runner.class it is fine until here but when I try to use
Logger.class in the Fact.class it gives me the problem "Cycle exists in module dependencies, Module ". I know modules are prevent to Cycle dependencies. But then
what is the solution for the situations like this>

Answer (score 0):

This is a false dependency loop because of how you structured your modules.
Move `Logger` into its own module and import it in the other two projects.  This is the general solution: factor out the dependency that is artificially causing the loop.

If you have a real circular dependency, you need to rearchitect the entire system to prevent it, but you do not have that situation here.

Comment: Can you, please, elaborate your answer. I mean I'm still confused. When I read *module1 requires module2* **and** *module2 requires module1*, how come it is not cyclic dependency?